# How to trace attribute changes of file in Linux system call layer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

How to trace attribute changes in Linux kernel system call layer.

Create a file name as test.txt

touch test.txt -> In this case access time got changed. In VFS layer this can be trace with "setattr" but how this can be trace in sys call layer?

Comment: Another approach would avoid the kernel and use [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities in user land.

Comment: Yes true.. but wanted to explore in kernel

Answer (score 0):

The function utimensat() is used by touch to do that. You can trace it with 'strace touch test.txt'.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimensat.html

Any write() or read() system calls will modify the access time (if the mount options don't prevent it).

Outside of manipulating directly the access time using explicit system call like 'touch' do, the Linux kernel use the rules defined by the atime mounting options of the filesystem to define when it will modify the access time. Search for the word atime into the mount manual page to see the details of the rules.

A look at fs/utimes.c could help understanding the system calls involved into atime modification.

Comment: This is not specific to touch and modification like echo "hello">test.txt which sys call it goes through to modify the file attribute.. like in VFS it goes via setattr VFS call.

Comment: You specifically asked for the touch example and Linux kernel system call layer.

Comment: No. Its in general setting of file attribute gets updated via which sys call in kernel?

Comment: In general ? It depend on the filesystem mount options and only indirectly from variouses system calls that can possibly end up updating the access time.